# Why my while loops still run when the value is pass the condition

Tags: python, while-loop

So i start working on a project to compare the busy time of 2 person and output a list that have the available time for them both to set an appointment
Input :

```
Person 1 = [["9:00", "10:30"], ["12:00", "13:00"], ["16:00", "18:00"]]
Person 2 = [["10:00", "11:30"], ["12:30", "14:30"], ["14:30", "15:00"], ['16:00', '17:00']]
```

Output :

```
list = [["11:30","1200"],["15:00","16:00"]]
```

```
def Gettime(time1, time2):
    hour1, minutes1 = time1.split(":")
    hour2, minutes2 = time2.split(":")
    int_time1 = int(hour1) * 60 + int(minutes1)
    int_time2 = int(hour2) * 60 + int(minutes2)
    if int_time1 <= int_time2:
        return 1
    elif int_time1 > int_time2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0


def FreeTime(sch1, sch2):
    list_nottime = []
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    #while p2 < len(sch2) :
        #while p1 < len(sch1):
    while p1 < len(sch1) or p2 <len(sch2):
         if Gettime(sch1[p1][x], sch2[p2][y]) == 1:
            #print(sch1[p1][x], sch2[p2][y])
            list_nottime.append(sch1[p1][x])
            x += 1
            if x == 2:
                x = 0
                p1 += 1

         if Gettime(sch1[p1][x], sch2[p2][y]) == 2:
            #print(sch1[p1][x], sch2[p2][y])
            list_nottime.append(sch2[p2][y])
            y += 1
            if y == 2:
                y = 0
                p2 += 1
```

So at this end (right above) `p2 == 4` and our while condition is `p2 < len(Sch2)` (which is equal to 4) 
and it still run the loops then it errors.
plz check  and fix it Tks you guys a ton!!!!(i'm not native speaker so my english is bad af)

Comment: Please provide example(s) of how you are calling these functions.

Comment: When you increment `p2` to the length of `sch2`, you keep running the inner loop, so it will try to access outside the `p2` list.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is before you call the second while loop, you are incrementing the value for `p1` and the condition in the second while loop accesses `sch[p1]` which might be going out of bounds for the given array. You need to save p1 in a temporary variable and use that value instead before updating the value of `p1`.

Or you need a condition to check for the edge or boundary cases. The same goes for p2 where it is being incremented in the second inner loop and the first one might try to access it with the index going out of bounds.

Comment: yeah but functionally even `p1` would throw off an error right?

Comment: You're right, it will try to use `p1` in the second `if`. Using `elif` would also fix that.

Comment: OH actually i have used while p1 <len(Sch1) or p2 < len(Sch2) instead of those ::while p2 < len(sch2) :
        while p1 < len(sch1): but it still not working